# Unity C#: rendering a group of sprites?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rendering, tile

So I created an Object called "Tile", that holds some properties like "isSolid" etc. I then drew to basic sprites "Air" and "Sand" that I shwushed the Tile Script on. Now I want to do the following; I have a script that Holds a 2d array   "Tile[,] map = new Tile[30,100];", and in the Start() routine I filled each element with the sand tile. Now I got the following question: how do I put the 2000 sprites on the screen? Later on I will just draw a 20x10 field depending on the players position but still, how can I draw a group of Sprites most effectively? Is there a way I can do some kind of batching, so that I can just instantiate on new sprite each Update() call that contains every sprite I want to draw or how would I do that?

```
public class WorldGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int Width = 100;
    public int Height = 20;

    public Tile t1_Air;
    public Tile t2_Sand;

    public string csvMap;
    readonly int offset = 1;

    Tile[,] map = new Tile[20, 100];

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
            {
                if (y < 10)
                    map[x, y] = t2_Sand;
                else map[x, y] = t1_Air;                  
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //draw the tiles held in the map here
    }
}
```

Comment: I will later read a csv file to create a level in the Start() function from there

Comment: Sounds like a job for a [tilemap](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Tilemap.html).

Comment: I will try that feature, thanks